# PHP Mail function not working in codigniter form MSP Cpanel live Windows Server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter PHP framework. I have used PHP mail function for sending mail not used SMTP mail send in my code. my code is working fine when use this code from live this error will come.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port
> 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use
> ini_set()
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1896
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
> C:\Domains\gdespatchhub.com\couriertracking.gdespatchhub.com\wwwroot\application\controllers\SuperAdmin\Users.php
> Line: 52 Function: send
>
> File:
> C:\Domains\gdespatchhub.com\couriertracking.gdespatchhub.com\wwwroot\index.php
> Line: 315 Function: require_once

I have used MSPControl Panel Windows Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no mail server running on that machine or it's not using port 25. 
You need to foind out the correct settings for the mail server and edit your php.ini (parameters smtp_server and smtp_port according to these.

Comment: it is live server Mr.Jan-Hendrik. What i do please help me